# Are there any drawbacks to using two opposite listeners?

Tags: object-oriented

In OOP there is a common pattern of using listeners and events.

Recently I've come upon a task where two opposite listeners were setup to accomplish needed logic:

```
private ValueChanger createValueChanger(UIComponentFactory f) {
    // ValueChanger is some kind of user facing UI component
    ValueChanger comp = f.createValueChanger();
    comp.addChangeListener(changeEvent -> {
        Value newValue = comp.getValue();
        if (!model.getValue().equals(newValue))
            model.setValue(newValue);
    });
    model.addValueChangeListener(newValue -> {
        if (!comp.getValue().equals(newValue))
            comp.setValue(newValue);
    });
}
```

Both `comp` and `model` fire events when corresponding `setValue` methods are called.

Such a design is needed because `comp` created in this method is not the only component that can call `model.setValue`.

Are the any possible drawbacks to such an approach in the future? Maybe there are other ways to organize handling of such events?

Comment: Isn't that kind of the whole point:  being able to assign multiple events to a listener?  The only drawback I can think of is it sometimes gets called twice for the same operation, so it would be useful if your operation were idempotent.

Comment: You're starting to reinvent an actor model. Might want to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The code you describe shows two objects that update each other based on an event. The risk of such a setup is that they may get into an endless loop where they continually update each other.

**However** you seem to have addressed this issue by checking if the value is changed before setting it.

- Object A: value is different, set it.
- New event fires because of change.
- Object B: value is different, set it.
- New event fires because of change.
- Object A: value is the same, ignore. Do not fire event.

This appears to be safe to me.